# Excel VBA UserForm, input data from textbox in a cell, cell is based on value in combobox

Tags: excel, vba, userform, excel-2016

I am having an excel file with a bunch of UserForms, they are all working well. but I got stuck on one part.

I have a userform with a combobox1 and a textbox1.

in the combobox you can select 17,19,21,23,25,25+
in the textbox a numeric value should be typed, for e.g. 80

based on the selected value in the Combobox1 (17,19,21,23,25,25+) I want the data from the textbox (80) to be inserted in respectively column H,I,J,K,L or M of the active row. yet I cannot figure out how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's rather easy:
The items in the Combobox are indexed, the first item has index 0, the second 1 and so on. You can get the selected item with the property `ListIndex`. If nothing is selected, it returns -1, else the index of the selected item.

Now all you need is to use this as offset to the cell in the current row and column "H". Put the following sub into the form code and call it from whatever event routine you want (button, change-event of the textbox, form close...) Just change the names `TextBox1` and `ComboBox1` to the names of your controls.

```
Sub PutValueToSheet()
    If Me.TextBox1 = "" Or Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "H").Offset(0, Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex)
    cell.Value = Me.TextBox1
End Sub
```

Comment: should it not be:
Offset(0, Me.ComboBox1.Value)

Comment: @RedHare  Nope, the `Value` gives the text of the selected item (eg "21" or "25+").

Comment: I know but now the value of the combobox does nothing. Perhaps I missunderstand it complete.

Comment: @FunThomas, thanks a lot, i am trying to test this but I the combobox does only show 17. I listed the combobox as "   ComboBox2.List = [PRODUCTION!h5:m5].Value" what am i doing wrong?

Comment: SOLVED IT WITH: Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRng As Range

Set myRng = Worksheets("PRODUCTION").Range("i5:N5")

With Me.ComboBox2
For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
.AddItem myCell.Value
Next myCell
End With